# Regex to match multiple groups all optional

Tags: regex

Input string is "bla bla 1:term1 bla bla 2:term2 bla bla 3:term3 bla bla"
ALL words are optional in this string and may not appear.

I'd like to capture named groups for term1, term2, term3. I tried this regex w/o success:

```
"(\b1:(?P<one>\w+))?.*?(\b2:(?P<two>\w+))?.*?(\b3:(?P<three>\w+))?"
```

It actually works if I remove the ? after each outer group and all the groups are present in the string. But I fail to make them optional.
Would appreciate some help

Comment: Do they always appear in this order? Also, what language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture the word following `:` so `:(\w+)` will do it:

```
$ egrep -o ":(\w+)" <<< "bla bla 1:term1 bla bla 2:term2 bla bla 3:term3 bla bla"
:term1
:term2
:term3
```

Capture group one will contain `term1`, two `term2` ect..

You might also be interested in [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=:)\w+" <<< "bla bla 1:term1 bla bla 2:term2 bla bla 3:term3 bla"
term1
term2
term3
```